# Keep TableRow columns a static length in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-cardview

I have a card view with an image and a few text views as shown below.

[image]

This is exactly how I want everything to be positioned, however whenever text is placed where name and race are the column widths expand putting everything out of position as shown below.

[image]

I would like everything to stay in place but not sure where I'm going wrong.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#2f2f2f"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbImageView"
        android:background="@drawable/soul_bg" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name:"
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:textColor="#FFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HP:"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:id="@+id/hpTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ATK:"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:id="@+id/atkTextView" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Race:"
                android:id="@+id/typeTextView"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DEF"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:id="@+id/defTextView"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WIS"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:id="@+id/wisTextView"
                 />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: use weight concept for view.

Comment: you need to use weight for this @M0rty

Comment: Where do I need to add the weights? I tried on the textviews but that didn't work

Comment: @AmitVaghela where do I need to place the weight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this way , you can apply **weightSum** , Try this below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#2f2f2f"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/soul_bg" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
                android:weightSum="6">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Name:"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hpTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="HP:"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/atkTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="ATK:"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/typeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Race:"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/defTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="DEF"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/wisTextView"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="WIS"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue

Comment: it will remain at same position and will be applicable in all device sizes as it is given weightsum. try my edited answer @M0rty

Comment: the HP and DEF column are still out of position

Comment: okay. you were right, actually i forgot to give weight to TextView. so its done i upadated my answer@M0rty

Comment: Awesome that seemed to work, but it has cause another issue. The TableLayout is slightly overlapping the image @AmitVaghela

Comment: you have to make different size images as per your devices otherwise it will give different results @M0rty

Answer (score 2):

apply `android:weightSum` to parent layout and `android:layout_weight` to child layout/view.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HP:"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/hpTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ATK:"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:id="@+id/atkTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
 </TableRow>
```